# I want to delete last letters of existing Contacts using Batch class. Is it possible? I want to delete all "sfdcpoint" letters

Tags: batch, class, delete

```apex
global class BatchApexExample implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // collect the batches of records or objects to be passed to execute
         
        String query = 'SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
     
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> conList) {
        
        // process each batch of records default size is 200
        for(Contact cont : conList) {        
            // Update the Contact Name 
            if(cont.LastName == (%sfdcpoint)){
                cont.remove(sfdcpoint);
            }
               }
        
        try {
            // Update the Account Record
            update conList;
         
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.debug(e);
        }
     }
     
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // execute any post-processing operations like sending email
    }
}
```

---

I attached picture of my Contacts

[image]

Comment: Hi David Reed. Did you delete my question with picture?

Comment: I _moved_ it to be an edit to this question. Please always use the [edit] function to add details - do not post an answer unless you have a solution to share. See [ask] and [answer] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            if(cont.LastName == (%sfdcpoint)){
                cont.remove(sfdcpoint);
            }
```

This is not valid Apex syntax. What you need is found in the class reference for the [`String`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) class. Specifically, you would want the `endsWith()` method to check for the suffix you are interested in, but since the `String` class offers a `removeEnd()` method you can simplify even further:

```
cont.LastName = cont.LastName.removeEnd('sfdcpoint');
```

You should almost never write an exception handler that does nothing but `System.debug()`. All that is going to do is *hide* real problems so that you never observe them.

And there's generally no reason for this to be `global` unless you're building or working with a managed package. Stick with `public` unless you specifically know you need `global`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work, also make sure you create a new list so that the updates are fired on only required records and not all records.

```
List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact LIMIT 10];
List<Contact> conToBeUpdated = new List<Contact>();
for (Contact cont : contacts) {
    System.debug(cont.LastName);
    // Update the Contact Name 
    if (cont.LastName.endsWith('sfdcpoint')) {
        String str = cont.LastName.replace('sfdcpoint', '');
        cont.LastName = str;
        conToBeUpdated.add(cont);
    }
}

if(!conToBeUpdated.isEmpty()) {
    // Better to use Database class and iterate the saveresult and log your failed records
    List<Database.SaveResult> saveResults = Database.update(conToBeUpdated, false);
}
```

Also make sure to check if its only `sfdcpoint` and not caps `Sfdcpoint`

Or you can change your query to query for only records with `sfdcpoint` in LastName

Your query could be `SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contact WHERE LastName LIKE '%sfdcpoint'` if you are sure that `sfdcpoint` is alwways at the end of lastName

Comment: Thank you for all professionals. It worked. I'm happy!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
   return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id, LastName 
                                     FROM Contact 
                                     WHERE LastName Like '%sfdcpoint']);
}
 
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> contacts) {
    for(Contact c : contacts) {        
        c.LastName = c.LastName.removeEnd('sfdcpoint');
    }
    update contacts;
 }
```

**Notes**

1. Let SOQL do the work of filtering. Your query was going to do a tablescan anyway so no loss in performance
2. Use public, not global modifier
3. Don't have exception trapping that does debug. If the update fails, you can query for failed batches in finish() and do something relevant. Or, use the new [BatchApexErrorEvent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm?search_text=batch).
4. Contact.LastName is a required schema field so you don't have to test for null before using `removeEnd(..)`